# ListBox с возможностью редактирования

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Помогите сделать ListBox с возможностью редактирования. Только не просто TextBox в качестве ItemTemplate. А как в TreeView, чтобы при двойном клике на элементе он становился доступным для редактирования, а при потере фокуса переставал.

Comment: Может быть, `DataGrid`?

Comment: @VladD врятли... Во первых выглядеть не так будет, во вторых редактироваться будет с одного клика, а не с двойного, и вообще этот ListBox у меня должен быть по задумке эдаким переключателем вкладок, просто я хочу чтобы и имена этих вкладок можно было тоже редактировать.

Comment: @DarkByte там можно убрать хидеры и слева и будет выглядеть точно так же. И в нем можно сделать редактирование по 1 клику. Но в DataGrid есть возможность задать шаблон in-place edit, а в ListBox нельзя

Comment: Так мне то надо по двойному, а не по одинарному!!!

Comment: Вот и придётся писать свой велосипед только потому, что хочется по двойному клику.

Comment: @Monk неужели для этого в WPF ничего не предусмотрено встроенного?

Comment: Встроенный - DataGrid

Comment: @Monk но как в нем сделать редактирование по двойному клику?